# A complex problem related to Maximum Modulus Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Suppose $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb D$ and $|f(z)|\rightarrow 1$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1^-$. Show that the number of solutions of $f(z)=\alpha$ is the same for all $\alpha$ in $\mathbb D$.

I guess try to express $f$ in the Blaschke Product form, but in the step to show that $f$ can be directly expressed as Blaschke Product form, I got stuck. Anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Just use the argument principle. The image of a circle close to the unit circle (from inside) is very close to the unit circle. The number of solutions of $f(z)=\alpha$, assuming we took the circle large enough to enclose $\alpha$ is the winding number of that image around $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks, that's smart, got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: take a circular contour just inside the disk, and use the Argument Principle.